# Use component as html in React with SweetAlert 2

Tags: reactjs, sweetalert, sweetalert2

How can I use a component as html body in ReactJs with SweetAlert2? I call `swal` on click event.

```
swal({
  title: "Title",
  html: <SomeComponent onChange={this.handleChange}/>
});
```

I can't use `ReactDOM.render(<SomeComponent onChange={this.handleChange}/>)` because I have to call `handleChange()` on `onChange` event.

Comment: I think you are trying to use SweetAlert for the wrong purpose. You have the possibility to use content for html element and onConfirm as callback. But maybe you are looking for a Modal.

Comment: in Angular, you can do it with `*swalPortal` for using component or any html directly (not as string) in `Swal`. but in React you can't do it AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

u can use:

```
const modalComponent = document.createElement("div");
ReactDOM.render(<YouComponent />, modalComponent )

swal({
html: modalComponent 
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).